# como hacer para detectar un valor incorrecto dentro de una variable

Tags: javascript, condiciones

mi problema con este codigo es sencillo pero no consigo solventarlo, lo unico que necesito es que si en la variable numero la cual introducimos por teclado no es un numero como le estamos pidiendo sino que se a introducido letras entonces que me salte el mensaje de alert y que me vulva a pedir  numeros. Gracias un saludo humilde de un intento de programador :)

CODIGO :

//declaramos variables

```
    var numero,suma,media;
    var contador;


    //inicializar variables o asignar

    contador = 0 ;
    suma = 0.0 ;//la ponemos con decimal porque es float 

    //proceso del bucle

    do //vamos a poner numeros asta el 0 el 0 sera el numero de escape para salir del bucle (do = hacer)
    {
        numero=parseFloat(prompt("numero (con 0 se sale): "));

        if (numero==null ){
            alert("no se a introducido un numero");

        }
        else { 
        suma=suma+parseFloat(numero);// esto es la suma de la suma anterior + el numero del parsefloat
        contador=contador+1;//con esto puedo tener una lista de cuantos numeros e intorducido
        }


    }while (numero!=0) /*esto significa repetir el (do), mientras (k es while)
    el numero que introduzcamos no sea 0 ,asi se escribe diferente (numero!=0)
    cualquier numero que no sea 0 el bucle del (do) seguira */


      media=suma/(contador-1);
      document.write("La <b> La media </b> es de : " + media + " y <b> La suma <b> es de : " + suma);
```

Comment: Ya probaste con una `expresion regular`?

Comment: Hola daniel si si probé pero o no supe hacer bien la expresion regular o simplemente no funciono jejejeje gracias igualmente daniel un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con `isNaN()` asi:

```js
var numero,suma,media;
    var contador;


    //inicializar variables o asignar

    contador = 0 ;
    suma = 0.0 ;//la ponemos con decimal porque es float 

    //proceso del bucle

    do //vamos a poner numeros asta el 0 el 0 sera el numero de escape para salir del bucle (do = hacer)
    {
        numero=parseFloat(prompt("numero (con 0 se sale): "));

        if (numero==null || isNaN(numero)){
            alert("no se a introducido un numero");

        }
        else { 
        suma=suma+parseFloat(numero);// esto es la suma de la suma anterior + el numero del parsefloat
        contador=contador+1;//con esto puedo tener una lista de cuantos numeros e intorducido
        }


    }while (numero!=0) /*esto significa repetir el (do), mientras (k es while)
    el numero que introduzcamos no sea 0 ,asi se escribe diferente (numero!=0)
    cualquier numero que no sea 0 el bucle del (do) seguira */


      media=suma/(contador-1);
      document.write("La <b> La media </b> es de : " + media + " y <b> La suma <b> es de : " + suma);
```

Comment: Hola alan ya esta tu solucion a sido perfecto , yo ya probé el isNaN(numero) pero lo probé mal creo que puse  numero==isNaN() o alguna cosa así jrjejejeeje ya veo porque no me funciona estaba mal escrito .Muchas gracias alan un saludo.

Comment: Ya intentaste ingresar un número y después letras? por ejemplo **345fg** lo tomaría como número, bueno sólo tomaría el 345, eso no afectaría?

Comment: Si tmb lo  e probado pero no me afecta al resultado que quería tener con esto ya me basta para su función .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar ese control utilizando la función [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN)

Éste te retorna true en caso de no poder convertirlo a un número y false en caso contrario.

```
isNaN(NaN) //devuelve true
isNaN("string") //devuelve true
isNaN("12") //devuelve false
isNaN(12) //devuelve false
```

Tambíen es posible realizar ese control utilizando expresiones regulares

```
var reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$') //Ésto seriva válido para números enteros
console.log(reg.test("1"));
```

Comment: Ostras esto me lo apunto tmb es muy interesante para futuros códigos , gracias cjara .